# Coalgebras(or quantum groups) which admit a linear operator satisfying certain functional equation

Tags: quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

What is an example of a coalgebra $C$ which admit a linear operator $T$, different from scalar operators $T=\lambda Id$, which satisfy $$(T\otimes T)\circ \Delta=\Delta \circ T^2 $$ but $C$ is not isomorphic to a subcoalgebra of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ or the trigonometric coalgebra generated by $c=cos, s=sin$?

Note that the differentiation operator on these coalgebras satisfies the above functional equation.

Our next question is the following:
 Does the above functional equation implies the automatic continuity of $T$ when $T$ is a symmetric operator on a quantum group?(By symmetricity of $T$ we mean $T(a^*)={(T(a))}^*$

**Edit:** According to the comment of Konstantinos, I add this link as a motivation for this question:

http://bims.iranjournals.ir/article_872_fd7287eb7f1365d9156e9da3ccb25196.pdf

Comment: Do you mean $T^2=T\circ T$ ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  yes $T^2=T\circ T$.

Comment: Dually on algebras this would be an operator satisfying $T(x)T(y)=T(T(xy))$; an example is multiplication by a central element.

Comment: Using the dual language written by @მამუკაჯიბლაძე (I'm sure this could be translated back easily, but prefer algebra to coalgebra): The equation implies that $T(C)$ is a (not necessarily unital) subalgebra. Letting $x = 1$, we have that $T(1) T(y) = T(T(y))$ (and similarly, $T(x) T(1) = T(T(x))$), so $T(1)$ is central within $T(C)$ and $T$ acts on $T(C)$ by multiplication by $T(1)$.

Comment: Using the algebra (but switching to the notation $T^*$ and $C^*$, to denote that those are on the dual space to $C$), some interesting additional hypotheses present themselves. @AliTaghavi, is it the case that $T^*$ is injective, and/or that $T^*(1)$ isn't a zero-divisor?

Comment: Ali, may i ask for some details on the motivation of this question? In particular, i would like to know whether you are aware of some connection to physics?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  To be honnest I did not have any physical motivation. Regarding mathematical motivation,  the standard differentiation satisfies the functional equation for coalgebras. Now if we consider the "Algebra" analogy of this equation  in the context of C* algebras we have automatic continiuity provided we have symmetric property. I wrote the motivations in a paper which link is available in my MO profile"on a functional equation for symmetric operator on C* algebras"

Comment: Your paper is very interesting indeed. Maybe you should edit the OP and add the citation to the main body. I think htat would add value to the OP.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  Dear Konstantinos Thank you very much for your comment. I add the linked paper.

Answer (score 6):

About your first question:
Since you are asking for an example, take any group hopf algebra $k\mathbb{G}$, pick some subset $S\subset \mathbb{G}$ and denote  $kS$ the linear subspace of $k\mathbb{G}$ generated by the set $S$.  Let $T:k\mathbb{G}\rightarrow kS\subset k\mathbb{G}$ be the projection operator onto that subspace. Then your property is  satisfied, by direct computation of both sides of your equation: 
$$
\Delta\circ T^2\big(\sum_{g\in\mathbb{G}}k_g g\big)=\sum_{g\in S}k_g g\otimes g=(T\otimes T)\circ\Delta\big(\sum_{g\in\mathbb{G}}k_g g\big)
$$
since $T(g)=g$, if $g\in S\subset \mathbb{G}$ and $T(g)=0$, if $g\in G\setminus S$.

From a more general point of view, since $(f\otimes f)\circ \Delta=\Delta\circ f$ is -by definition- satisfied for any morphism of coalgebras, then your functional equation should be satisfied for any idempotent ( i.e. $T^2=T$) coalgebra endomorphism $T:C\rightarrow C$.

**Edit:** Attempting a translation of the comments to the OP, on the dual relation on algebras, by users : @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე and @user44191:
The functional equation stated at the OP implies that:
a). $\Delta\big(T^2(C)\big)\subseteq T(C)\otimes T(C))$ and
b). $T^2$ acts on $C$ as: 
$$T^2(c)=\varepsilon\big(T^2(c)_1\big)T^2(c)_2=T^2(c)_1\varepsilon\big(T^2(c)_2\big)= \\ =\varepsilon\big(T(c_1)\big)T(c_2)=T(c_1)\varepsilon\big(T(c_2)\big)$$
(you can get that by applying $Id\otimes\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon\otimes Id$ on both sides of the functional equation at the OP $(T\otimes T)\circ \Delta=\Delta \circ T^2$).

However, i do not know about your second question in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I think your translation is incorrect; removing the $T$ (analogous to where I essentially said $T(xy) \in C$), the inclusion goes in the other direction, that is, $(T \otimes T) \circ \Delta(C) = \Delta(T(T(C)) \subseteq \Delta(T(C))$.

Comment: I think instead of $T(C)$, $T^{-1}(0)$ is likely to be more useful.

Comment: @user44191, thank you for your feedback. You are probably right in your observation that $T(C)$ need not be a subcoalgebra in general. So the first point of the "translation" is probably incorrect. I will remove it and try to come back after i will give it some more thought.

Comment: In any case, this (i mean your dual statement on algebras) seems to be an interesting remark. Maybe it would be useful to discuss this and its possible translation, in a separate question (since this is not what the OP is asking about).

Comment: @user44191, my initial thought when i read your dual comment, was that $T(C)$ or $T^2(C)$ should be picked and that they would be coideals rather than subcoalgebras, in order to "read" the argument in the coalgebra language. However your proposal on picking $T^{-1}(0)$ seems interesting as well.

Comment: There is no direct connection between $T(C)$ and $T^*(C^*)$; instead, $T^{-1}(0)$ is the subspace of $C$ that "identifies" $T^*(C^*)$, the subalgebra in the dual of $C$, and so is its natural counterpart. The right side of the resulting equation is then clear: $(\Delta \circ T^2)(T^{-1}(0)) = 0$, so $((T \otimes T) \circ \Delta)(T^{-1}(0)) = 0$. I think that should imply that $T^{-1}(0)$ is a coideal.

Comment: And the statement that $T^*$ acts on $T^*(1)$ on $T^*(C^*)$ should be equivalent to a statement on the quotient coalgebra $C/T^{-1}$.

Comment: I am not sure why $T^{-1}(0)$ should be a coideal. Am i missing something simple ?

Comment: I've made a chat:https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89079/discuss-https-mathoverflow-net-questions-321717-coalgebrasor-quantum-groups-whi

Comment: As a note, the example you have is in fact dual to a case of what @მამუკაჯიბლაძე wrote in the comments to the main post; the dual algebra to the group coalgebra is commutative, and the action you've chosen comes from multiplication by the idempotent $\mathbf{1}_S$ (which is central because the algebra is commutative).

Comment: @ user44191: Nice! and maybe it would be even better, if all these notes and comments, including the OP and the answer, were recorded in  the form of  a new question here (towards particular or general solutions of the OP functional equation) or maybe in a post in nLab.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou  Thanks  for  your  suggestion. I read  your  comment  very  late(just now). i  am  sorry about that.